# Backend\Controllers\Users must define property $relationConfig

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins

I like to build a Plugin where Frontend User belongsTo BackendUser ( One to Many Relation ). For the backend User i want to display an partial with Relation Manager to add many Frontend Users to BackendUser.  If i try dynamically define a property on Plugin.php like:

```
use Backend\Models\User as BackendUser;
use Backend\Controllers\Users as BackendUsersController;


public function boot(){    
    BackendUsersController::extend(function($controller) {  
        $controller->implement[] = 'Backend.Behaviors.RelationController';  
        $controller->relationConfig = '$/plg-user/plg/controllers/plg-ctr/config_relation.yaml'  
    });
});
```

i get an Error : Class Backend\Controllers\Users must define property $relationConfig used by Backend\Behaviors\RelationController behavior

If i try to put manually :

```
public $relationConfig = '$/plg-user/plg/controllers/plg-ctr/config_relation.yaml'
```

to the Backend\Controllers\Users Controller everything woks.

any Idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises because any object that implements the `October\Rain\Extension\ExtendableTrait` trait (like the Users controller does, which is how you can call `::extend()` on it) prevents undeclared properties from being auto-declared on first assignment.

Instead, you must use the `addDynamicProperty($property, $value)` method to add undeclared properties to the object. This was previously undocumented and was documented in [octobercms/docs@9d454c](https://github.com/octobercms/docs/commit/9d454c940cff02a53b99dbae3f1c989ba145b33d).

An example of working code for your case would now be

```
/**
 * Extend the BackendUsers controller to include the RelationController behavior
 */
BackendUsersController::extend(function($controller) {

    // Implement the list controller behavior dynamically
    $controller->implement[] = 'Backend.Behaviors.RelationController';

    // Declare the relationConfig property dynamically for the RelationController behavior to use
    $controller->addDynamicProperty('relationConfig', '$/plg-user/plg/controllers/plg-ctr/config_relation.yaml');
});
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much Luke your solutions work's perfect ;)

Comment: Thanks for updating the document

Answer (score 0):

I've extended the front-end user controller in the exact same way and it works:

```
UsersController::extend(function($controller){
    if(!isset($controller->implement['Backend.Behaviors.RelationController'])) {
        $controller->implement[] = 'Backend.Behaviors.RelationController';
    }
    $controller->relationConfig  =  '$/meysam/profile/controllers/profile/config_relations.yaml';
});
```

I think the difference is that `relationConfig` has already been defined in the front-end user controller class:

```
class Users extends Controller
{
    public $implement = [
        'Backend.Behaviors.FormController',
        'Backend.Behaviors.ListController'
    ];

    public $formConfig = 'config_form.yaml';
    public $listConfig = 'config_list.yaml';
    public $relationConfig;
```

And `public $relationConfig;` does not exist in the backend user controller. A workaround might be to create your own backend user controller class which inherits from `Backend\Controllers\Users` and add a `public $relationConfig;` property to it. This may not be the best solution though.

Comment: Hi Meysam.... Thank you ... I also think that creating my own Backend User Controller class is not the best solution ;) ... Is it not possible to add the public $relationConfig; property to the Backend\Controllers\Users class dynamically ?

Comment: @JBee That could be possible, I don't know how to do that and am interested to know.

Comment: Meysam see my answer above